# Split a string into two variables using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to split a string into two parts like

> Supporter->VIP

in NodeJS. For example:

```
var Old = Supporter
var New = VIP
```

Would I have to use `.split()` somehow? Or is there a way I can use a RegExp? The `->` would always be in between the two.

Sorry I couldn't be more descriptive. I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split the string and take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
var [o, n] = 'Supporter->VIP'.split('->');

console.log(o, n);
```